# get hidden nested data value from datatable server side

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

i have json data like this :

```
[{"id_asset":"4b5c2a52-a4fb-44f3-8b15-be369878ff1e","id_safety":{"id_safety":"64fa5f8b-44c2-4906-9bf8-27f826e026a5","referensi":"default","keterangan":"default","safety_procedure":"default","alat_safety":"default"},"asset_name":"roll","serial":"r129","asset_code":"C1-R1","parent_code":"C1-R11","purchase_date":"2020-03-03","grup":"bahan bakar","model":"CR123","location":"bengkel","asset_tag":"C1222","warranty":12.0,"safety_referensi":"default","vendor":"daeyang","consume":0,"stok":0,"end_balance":0,"price":1111.0},{"id_asset":"5ef6c6f2-9cfd-475a-8d21-5ade18d2fd20","id_safety":null,"asset_name":"C01829XX","serial":"C1-R11","asset_code":"xxx","parent_code":"","purchase_date":"2020-02-24","grup":"bahan baku sipil","model":"bengkel","location":"C1111","asset_tag":"xx","warranty":0.0,"safety_referensi":"daeyang","vendor":"sss","consume":0,"stok":0,"end_balance":0,"price":1111111.0}]
```

and i want get value from id_safety, (example: id_safety:64fa5f8b-44c2-4906-9bf8-27f826e026a5)  but when i click datatable always return undifined

this is js for select value :

```
var dat = $('#tabelass').DataTable().row('.selected').data();
       console.log(dat );
       alert("id_asset:" + dat ['id_asset'] + "\id_safety:" + dat ['id_safety.id_safety']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small issue in here. Just replace this in your code:

```
dat ['id_safety.id_safety']
```

with this:

```
dat['id_safety']['id_safety']
```

as `dat['id_safety']` retuns the inner object in this format:

```
{id_safety: "64fa5f8b-44c2-4906-9bf8-27f826e026a5", ... }
```

and in order to access the `id_safety` property in this object, you will need to do like:

```
dat['id_safety']['id_safety']
// returns "64fa5f8b-44c2-4906-9bf8-27f826e026a5"
```